# gcc LTO appears to strip debugging symbols

Tags: debugging, gcc, optimization, lto

I have project, running on an ARM Cortex-M4 processor, where I'm trying to include the gcc link-time optimization (LTO) feature.

Currently my compilation and linking flags are:

```
CFLAGS = -ggdb -ffunction-sections -Og
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-gc-sections
```

Everything works fine with these flags and I'm able to correctly debug the project.

Then I tried adding `-flto` to CFLAGS. Although the program works fine, I'm no longer able to debug the project, with gdb complaining of missing debugging symbols. Running `objdump -g` on the ELF file (with LTO enabled) gives the following output:

```
xxx.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm

Contents of the .debug_frame section:

00000000 0000000c ffffffff CIE
  Version:               1
  Augmentation:          ""
  Code alignment factor: 2
  Data alignment factor: -4
  Return address column: 14

  DW_CFA_def_cfa: r13 ofs 0

00000010 00000018 00000000 FDE cie=00000000 pc=08002a3c..08002a88
  DW_CFA_advance_loc: 2 to 08002a3e
  DW_CFA_def_cfa_offset: 16
  DW_CFA_offset: r4 at cfa-16
  DW_CFA_offset: r5 at cfa-12
  DW_CFA_offset: r6 at cfa-8
  DW_CFA_offset: r14 at cfa-4
  DW_CFA_nop

0000002c 0000000c ffffffff CIE
  Version:               1
  Augmentation:          ""
  Code alignment factor: 2
  Data alignment factor: -4
  Return address column: 14

  DW_CFA_def_cfa: r13 ofs 0

0000003c 0000000c 0000002c FDE cie=0000002c pc=08002a88..08002a98
```

Note the missing `.debug_info` section. Going back to the project settings and only removing `-flto` from CFLAGS solves the problem. `objdump -g` on the ELF file without LTO now shows a `.debug_info` section, filled with the proper references to the functions in my project, and debugging works fine again.

How to get LTO and debug symbols to play well together?

**Edit**: forgot to include my gcc information. I'm using the [GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded), and the test was performed on versions 5.4-2016q2 and 5.4-2016q3.

Comment: There is some information that may be of interest to you here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/early-debug

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not yet. I haven't tested on a newer version of gcc though.

Comment: @TrygveLaugstøl Update: I've just tested this on the latest version of the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain (6-2017-q1-update) and, at least according to objdump, the debug symbols are back. Unfortunately, since it's the weekend, I don't have access to my hardware to test it. I will report back when I do.

Comment: @swineone nice, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: GCC 8.2.0 does not state any longer that `-flto` and `-g` are incompatible, and Gold preserves DWARF sections with `--gc-sections`. The traditional BFD linker doesn't, however, but a linker script can be used to prevent stripping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation should have improved by now.
GCC 8 finally got the early debug info improvements:
http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2018/06/gcc-8-link-time-and-interprocedural.html

> While it was possible to build with LTO and -g and debug the resulting
> binary, the debug information was kind of messed up C, instead of
> debug info corresponding to the language program was originally
> written in. This is finally solved. [...] The main idea is to produce
> DWARF early during compilation, store it into object files and during
> link-time just copy necessary fragments to final object files without
> need for compiler to parse it and update it.

But note that `-gsplit-dwarf` won't work with LTO.

Comment: I decided to accept the answer despite not having actually tried it out with a newer version of gcc. If anyone tries and still has issues, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 8):

It's because gcc does not support combine `-flto` with `-g`.

You can find the details [GCC Online Docs - Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> "Combining `-flto` with `-g` is currently experimental and expected to
>   produce unexpected results."

When you use `-flto`, the `-g` will be ignored.

Comment: Currently 7.3.0 reads "Link-time optimization does not work well with generation of debugging information. Combining -flto with -g is currently experimental and expected to produce unexpected results."

Answer (score 0):

One can try using **attribute**((used)) or alternatively one can try using the debugging symbols in a way that does not change their values.